# What is the word for "money I want to spend in the future"?

Tags: finance

What would be the short English term for "money I want to spend in the future"? I ask because I've created a simple app for personal finances, where a user can add all the predicted spendings. Right now I call them "Predictions". I'm not sure if it's the right term. Someone suggested me "Expected Outgoings" or "Future Expenditures" but I would like something short and self-describing.

For example:

Fun 300
Lunch 200
Groceries 10

Each item from this list is a prediction.

Comment: ..........money

Answer (score 6):

You can use **budget**.

> budget
>   *noun* - an estimate of income and expenditure for a set period of time.
>   *synonyms* - financial plan, forecast; accounts, statement
>   *"your budget for the week"*

If in your app, budget has already been used for the sum of all predictions, you might call each estimated expense item in the budget: an **estimated expense**.

Comment: Well, in my case the budget will be the sum of all predictions, and not a single prediction.

Comment: The question is specifically only about future spends and budget does not work.

Comment: I've edited my question with some examples to better illustrate as I'm not allow to add link to my app in a question.

Comment: @PreetieSekhon That is strange, especially when one synonym of budget is *estimated expenses*.

Comment: @PreetieSekhon-What you describe is really the budgeted amount for each expense category.  You might call it *Planned Expenditures* or *Budget Allocation* or *Budget Amount*  but *budget* is the proper term.  I.e., you can say things like, "What's our budget for food?"  which means how much are we allowed to spend before going over our budget.

Comment: @zuzuleinen If in your app, *budget* has already been used for the sum of all predictions, you might call each estimated expense item, an **estimated expense**.

Comment: @DamkerngT. that is exactly what I meant.When the entire application is about 'budgeting', either the terms 'allocated budget' should be used. Alternatives could be projected spends or estimated expenses.A stand-alone 'budget' does not work.As far as synonyms go, the precise word used does depend on the usage and context.One size does not fit all!

Comment: @DamkerngT. So I must use 2 words? Doesn't exist a single word synonym?

Comment: If the context is clear, I believe you can use just either *estimated* or *expense*. I mean if it is clear to the user that every item on the screen is an expense, then the word *Estimated* would be sufficient. On the other hand, if it is clear that every item on the screen is an estimated one, then the word *Expense* (or *Expenses*, depending on where you place it) should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

These are you **anticipated expenses**. If you need something shorter, perhaps *anticipations*. If it's all desirable, expensive stuff, maybe *aspirations*. (*Hopes and dreams* seems a bit too poetic.)

Answer (score 0):

How about **allotment**? It is not as precise as Damkerng's **estimated expense** but it is less wordy. In making a budget you allot portions of money to each item. I have always considered the word to reference the future. NOAD seems to disagree:

> **allot**: give or apportion (something) to someone as a share or task

That definition seems more focused on present distribution than arrangement for the future. I sadly do not have access to higher-end dictionaries. I still think **allotment** would fit the job but do commenters have any insight on the meaning of **allot**?